# Cannot convert decryption code usingg Blowfish ECB from Java to Node.js

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, blowfish

I cannot seem to figure out what's causing the difference between languages. In Java I have:

```
byte[] buf = Base64.getDecoder().decode("AutMdzthDvPlE+UnhcHa2h4UZGPdme7t");
System.out.println(buf.length);
String key = "" + 2270457870L;
byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF8");
System.out.println(keyBytes.length);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "Blowfish"));

byte[] newBytes = cipher.doFinal(buf);
System.out.println(newBytes.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newBytes));
```

(runnable online at http://ideone.com/0dXuJL)

Then in Node I turned this into:

```
const buf = Buffer.from("AutMdzthDvPlE+UnhcHa2h4UZGPdme7t");
console.log(buf.length);
const keyBytes = Buffer.from('2270457870', 'utf8');
console.log(keyBytes.length);
const decipher = require('crypto').createDecipher('bf-ecb', keyBytes);

const buffers = [];
buffers.push(decipher.update(buf));
buffers.push(decipher.final());

const newBytes = Buffer.concat(buffers);
console.log(newBytes.length);
console.log(newBytes);
```

(runnable online at https://tonicdev.com/paulbgd/57b66c8ea0630d1400081ad0)

Which outputs the error: `error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. The string encoding is missing for `buf`. By default, `utf8` is used, but the string is actually base64-encoded. To remedy that use this instead:

   ```
   const buf = Buffer.from("AutMdzthDvPlE+UnhcHa2h4UZGPdme7t", "base64");
   ```
2. The second argument passed to `createDecipher()` is a *password*, *not* a *key*. The difference is that `createDecipher()` hashes the password argument (with MD5) to generate the key. Since you have the key already, what you want instead is [`createDecipheriv()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipheriv_algorithm_key_iv), which expects a key and IV. The IV argument can just be a zero-length Buffer since ECB mode does not utilize an IV. So use this instead:

   ```
   const decipher = require('crypto').createDecipheriv('bf-ecb', keyBytes, Buffer.alloc(0));
   ```

Lastly, if you want to match the bytes output from Java, you can replace `console.log(newBytes)` with something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < newBytes.length; ++i)
  process.stdout.write(newBytes.readInt8(i) + ' ');
console.log();
```

Comment: The base64 was just a mistake I made when copying it over, but I didn't realize that createDecipher was expecting a password! Thanks a ton.